# can I have azure Function App settings in form of json file on the azure cloud side?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Basically
could I have variables being set up in a json file,
so when I deploy my app from zip, they will get loaded?

I know I could have

```
local.settings.json
```

but this will work only locally. Is it possible with some file on remote (azure side)
so it loads nicely here?

[image]

Comment: Jus store it in blob and retrieve it each time?!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a service in the Azure which acts as a central repository for the Azure Services such as Web Apps, Functions Apps, etc. to store the parameters, application settings, keys, secrets, etc., which can be retrieved through code in the Application.

- You have the own SDKs & libraries for every Azure Function Stack such as .NET Framework, Core, Python, and JavaScript to access the Azure App Configuration and an practical also given by Microsoft in this [MS Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process) and visit this [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-best-practices#app-service-or-azure-functions-access-to-app-configuration) for more information.

You can define the configuration for getting the App Configuration store settings as Environment variable using the `IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder` class in the `Startup.cs` class file.

```cs
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder) 
{ 
string connstr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Storage_ConnectionString"); 
builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(connstr ); 
}
```

and we can get that configuration from all the function in a Azure Function project and also same app configuration store can be used by multiple function apps.